# Using Like Expression for Date Field using JPA 2.1

Tags: java, jpa

Am trying to perform a query with LIKE expression on a date field using a named query as shown below ;

```
public Users getResultsByDate(Date regDate){
 List<Users> dbUsers = new ArrayList<Users>();
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
 Query searchQuery = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("getUserByRegDate");
       searchQuery.setParameter("regDate", "%"+dateFormat.format(regDate)+"%");
try{
         dbUsers = searchQuery.getResultList();
     }
 catch(Exception ex){
         dbUsers = new ArrayList<Users>();
     }
 return dbUsers;
```

}

The name query in corresponding class is;

```
 @NamedQuery(name = "getUserByRegDate", query = "SELECT user FROM Users user WHERE user.regDate LIKE :regDate"),
```

The query was working using previous JPA 2.0 version. I get the following error when i execute the same when running on JPA 2.1;

> You have attempted to set a value of type class java.lang.String for
>   parameter :regDate with expected type of class java.util.Date ...

How can i resolve this when running on JPA 2.1 ? It's Working OK in JPA 2.0.

Comment: since a date is not a string (which LIKE is defined to take) what exactly do you expect?

Comment: @NeilStockton works perfectly in JPA 2.0.

Comment: `LIKE` is for strings, not for dates (or numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a native named query, transforming `user.reg_date` to string and then comparing it with the operator `like` to the parameter. In case of an Oracle DB it would be for example:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "getUserByRegDate", query = 
  "SELECT user FROM Users user WHERE TO_CHAR(user.reg_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY') LIKE :regDate"),
```

Comment: Thanks Boris, Your answer has led me in the right direction. I have used a NamedQuery like this;  @NamedQuery(name = "getUserByRegDate", query = "SELECT user FROM Users user WHERE FUNCTION('TO_CHAR',user.reg_date,'yyyy-MM-dd') LIKE :regDate") .

Answer (score 2):

JPA spec 4.6.10

> The syntax for the use of the comparison operator [NOT] LIKE in a
>   conditional expression is as follows:

```
like_expression ::=
string_expression [NOT] LIKE pattern_value [ESCAPE escape_character]
```

> The string_expression must have a string value. The pattern_value is a
>   string literal or a string-valued input parameter ...

So no, it does **not** "work" in JPA 2.0; it is **not** part of ANY JPA spec to use Date in LIKE expressions. It may have just worked by accident because some JPA provider (which one?) didn't do a check and enforce the JPA spec ...

Answer (score 0):

Key is to use DB functions 'TO_CHAR' (ORACLE) or MySQL function 'date_format' then user FUNCTION IN @NamedQuery as  shown below ;

**ORACLE DB**

```
@NamedQuery(name = "getUserByRegDate", query = "SELECT user FROM Users user WHERE FUNCTION('TO_CHAR',user.reg_date,'yyyy-MM-dd') LIKE :regDate")
```

**MySQL**

Change 'TO_CHAR' above  to 'date_format'

```
@NamedQuery(name = "getUserByRegDate", query = "SELECT user FROM Users user WHERE FUNCTION('date_format',user.reg_date,'%Y-%m-%d') LIKE :regDate")
```

Also see http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp for more info on the DATE_FORMAT MySQL Function.
Thanks.